# VBA Excel offset formula required for the below excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, database, offset

Please find the image of below excel sheet. I need `VBA` code for this one.

[image]

and result should be

[image].

A column combines with after b,c,d,e,f,g. Only bring the "YES" word and "NO" no need.

Comment: You could do this with Powerquery. Apart from that what did you try on your own or is this just a "Gimme the code" request"?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried and where you have run into problems. This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop. Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the VBA code, if you want to acheive it through the VBA only.

Here is source Sample image
[image]

And here is the Destination Image from the same sheet.
[image]

```
Sub TransposeAndFill()
'Declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim src As Range
Dim dst As Range

'Set worksheet and ranges
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set src = ws.Range("A1:G12") 'Source range
Set dst = ws.Range("I1:K1") 'Destination range

'Copy headers
ws.Range("I1").Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
ws.Range("J1").Value = "Seq"
ws.Range("K1").Value = "Result"

'Initialize row counter for destination range
k = 2

'Loop through columns of source range (except first column)
For i = 2 To src.Columns.Count
    'Loop through rows of source range (except first row)
    For j = 2 To src.Rows.Count
        'Copy site value from first column
        dst.Cells(k, 1).Value = src.Cells(j, 1).Value
        'Copy seq value from column header
        dst.Cells(k, 2).Value = src.Cells(1, i).Value
        'Copy result value from cell
        dst.Cells(k, 3).Value = src.Cells(j, i).Value
        'Increment row counter for destination range
        k = k + 1
    Next j
    'k = k + 1
Next i
```

End Sub